# create_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samples', when using nnfs

Tags: python

This code works:

```
import numpy as np
import nnfs

nnfs.init()

n_inputs = 2
n_neurons = 4

weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))

print(weights)
print(biases)
```

But this code does not work:

```
import numpy as np
import nnfs
from nnfs.datasets import spiral_data

nnfs.init()


# Dense layer
class Layer_Dense:

    # Layer initialization
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))

    # Forward pass
    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Calculate output values from input ones, weights and biases
        self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases


# Create dataset
X, y = spiral_data(samples=100, classes=3)

# Create Dense layer with 2 input features and 3 output values
dense1 = Layer_Dense(2, 3)

# Perform a forward pass of our training data through this layer
dense1.forward(X)

# Let's see output of the first few samples:
print(dense1.output[:5])
```

Specifically the line `X, y = spiral_data(samples=100, classes=3)`.

All libraries are imported. Can someone help please?

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/mikecallahan/PycharmProjects/Algos/ch3.py", line 24, in <module>
    X, y = spiral_data(samples=100, classes=3)
TypeError: create_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samples'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the NNFS package:

```
pip install --upgrade nnfs
```

(use pip according to your operating system, for example `pip3`)

You installed the NNFS package before the dataset functions were using keyworded parameters. We normalized that later and updated function parameter names.

Answer (score -1):

[nnfs](https://pypi.org/project/nnfs/) is missing in your project environment. Install it properly and rerun your program.

Attaching the screenshots:
[Install nnfs properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgmTH.png)

[Works fine after installing nnfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY7kt.png)

Comment: Apparently they were able to import nnfs just fine and then got an error when using it.

Answer (score -1):

By inspecting the package installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nnfs/`:

```
from nnfs.datasets.spiral import create_data
X, y = create_data(samples = 100, classes = 3)
```

Comment: That's the code that raises the exception, so how does this answer propose to solve the problem?